# Do we have any option in salesforce to make the mail as important in apex code?

Tags: apex, community, send-email

I am writing the code to send an email to our support group whenever the value goes more than the threshold level defined in the custom  setting. I want to make the mail as more important. Please suggest me which can attract more to look into mail.

```
//Sending Email

 Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using Messaging.SingleEmailMessage, you can use emailPriority method to set it.

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = 
    new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage(); 
// Set other values of mail
Mail.emailPriority = 'Highest';
```

---

**Added**: AFAIK, This method is still not mentioned in [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm) yet.

Values accepted in emailPriority are:

1. Highest
2. Normal
3. Lowest

Comment: Unfortunately its still not mentioned in documentation though.